# MarkLogic: Integrate Application Builder generated application into my custom application

Tags: marklogic

I am developing a custom MarkLogic application that has a few tabs for creating/editing taxonomies, working with documents etc.

One of my tabs is a search tab. Is it possible to save application generated in Application Builder in some folder inside my custom application and run it in my application tab without iFrames?

I understand that I can create my own code for getting data and formatting it for output. But existing Application Builder has a lot of cool features I would like to have. And I would like to be up-to-date with it without updating of my own code.

So does anybody know how to run Application Builder generated app under my custom MarkLogic application or implement similar functionality?

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this would be to use a combination of Roxy and Application Builder.  You can get Roxy from GitHub here: https://github.com/marklogic/roxy and then follow the instructions in Dave Cassel's blog here: http://blog.davidcassel.net/2013/03/roxy-deployer-and-application-builder/